# What does the phrase "wall-run around threats" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "wall-run around threats" in the following sentence from the description of the game Super Glitch Dash :

*There are some spots where you can **wall-run around threats** or even flip the level upside down for a quick escape.*

Here is a description of the game from a different source:

*Feel the rush of your reflexes as you swipe your way past axes, hammers, lasers, meat grinders and spikes while trying to navigate the insane obstacle courses that comprise each stage. Grind rails, flip upside down, and scream into all-new indoor environments as the rollercoaster-like worlds unfold before your very eyes. ([Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rogue.superglitchdash&hl=en_US&gl=US))*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 'wall-run' is where someone has enough momentum to be able to 'run up' a wall. In parkour, for example, a wall-run is a technique to climb obstacles taller than your jumping height.

However, looking at your link it appears to be a game that simulates running forwards through a pipe. A 'wall-run' in this context would be where you can use momentum to run 'around' the pipe. That is, as you are travelling forwards with speed, you are able to move sideways continuously  so as to circle the inner pipe and return to the bottom.